# Dynamically changing print in bash

Tags: bash, printf

I have a script that displays a menu for my applications with details about them such as PID, runtime, and other static data.

In this script I wait for a user input to preform some actions on the application such as kill \ start \ update.

I want to add to the data I'm displaying, a dynamically changing stat about its CPU usage, and say update it every second.

The problem is that with `printf "%s\r" "$(appCPUusage)"` is that it requires this print to be the last thing that appears on the screen but I need it to be somewhere in the center of the script, and put the refreshing of `$appCPUusage` on the background and still allow users to input their action and use the script.

Is that doable on bash?
[image]

On the `CPUsage` column is where I want the dynamically changing var to be.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a job for curses. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

Comment: @WayneVosberg seems like C programming isn't it? Is there a solution without leaving bash?

Comment: Not easily. Or portably (is that even a word?). It would all depend on your terminal emulation (echo $TERM). For example, look at the escape sequences for xterm: https://www.xfree86.org/4.8.0/ctlseqs.html